# Segue not passing UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I am trying to segue an array of images from a UICollectionViewController to a UITableViewController with static cells. The setup is that when a user presses a cell in the collection view controller, the UIImage in that cell segues to the UIImageView in the table view controller.

The problem is that the image is not appearing in the `UITableViewController`'s `UIImageView`.

I think that the `UIImage` is not being passed to the `UIImageView` in the `UITableViewController`.

Here is my relevant `UICollectionViewController` code:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class AddImageCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var mainImages = ["cup", "transport", "beach", "weather", "gear", "money", "technology-1", "web", "people", "nature", "draw", "technology", "screen", "shop", "arrow"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return mainImages.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width / 3
    let screenHeight = screenWidth

    let size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

    return size
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddImageCollectionViewCell


    // Configure the cell
    cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: mainImages[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "nextStep" {
        if let indexPaths = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems() {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddTableViewController
            //let photoViewController = destinationViewController.viewControllers[0] as! PhotoViewController
            destinationViewController.imageName = mainImages[indexPaths[0].row]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my relevant `UITableViewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Table view data source

@IBOutlet var photoImageView:UIImageView!

var content:Agenda!
var imageName:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

After selecting my cell in the Collection View Controller in the simulator, I get the following error message in the console:

> CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:

Comment: What exactly is your issue in `prepareForSegue`?  Is the code not entering the `if-let`?  Is your image construction failing?  Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to verify that the image is being assigned on the `destinationViewController`?

Comment: @JAL The image is not appearing in the `UITableViewController`'s `UIImageView`.

Comment: Did you step through every `if` in `prepareForSegue`?  Is the control flow what you are expecting?

Comment: @JAL When you say "step through", what do you mean?

Comment: Using a debugger set a breakpoint on the line `if segue.identifier == "nextStep" {`.  Then, step through the execution line-by-line.  If the code execution jumps to the return before you enter the next line, you know where the issue with your logic is.

Comment: @JAL Where is the return?

Comment: If you examine the result of `UIImage(named: mainImages[indexPath.row])`, what does it give you?

Comment: @PhillipMills How do I examine it?

Comment: Print it or use the debugger.

Comment: @PhillipMills Nothing appears in the debugger when I press the collection cell and segue to the table view, whilst in the simulator.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have updated my answer to include my new code and error message.

Comment: @JAL I have updated my answer to include my new code and error message.